# cant run SELECT HAVING query in HIVEQL

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have 2 columns in a table. Let's call them column A and B. I want to find A where the distinct count of B is more than 1. In SQL

```
select column_a
from table1
group by column_a
having count(distinct column_b) > 1;
```

For some reason, this does not run in HIVE. the error keep on saying

```
error while compiling statement: failed: semanticexception [error 10002]: line 4:22 invalid column reference 'column_b'
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Hive are you running?  I would imagine that this version would work well:

```
select column_a
from (select column_a, count(distinct column_b) as cnt
      from table1
      group by column_a
     ) a
having cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I only have access to the browser interface. How would i know what version this is? I know it is CDH5.4. Possibly Hive 1.0? If I get rid of the outer select and bring the having inside and add the count in my select, it would work

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it to work using

```
select column_a, count(distinct column_b)
from table1
group by column_a
having count(distinct column_b) > 1
```

thank you Gordon